# Are Android Google Api's available in China and how to test my app?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, vpn, google-fit-sdk

I'm using Google's API like Google Maps and Google Fit in my Android application and I'd like to know if they'd work in China.

And is there a way to test my app like it was in China? I tried looking for a free china vpn but didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: I can test your app.

Comment: Ah didn't think of that!
You can download it here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ifpen.gecoair&hl=zh-cn

(the current version is in english but the beta is in chinese)

Comment: Could you send it to my email.I couldn't download in the GooglePlay. 
   Email:keliuyue@gamil.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer from somebody that lived in China for 5 years.

Some Google Apis work, some Apis don't work and some Apis only work sometimes. It is very complicated to predict if they will continue working. China tries to block Google servers quite often.

Answering your question: **currently Google Maps don't work in China** and you'll have to use Baidu Maps or Bing Maps. Unless people are using a working VPN... in that case it will work.

From personal experience AstrillVPN is ok and should work 90% of the time if you want to test as if you were in China (but this might change with time) ;)